# derive an equation from an equation with $\log$ and $\tan$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, inverse, inverse-function

I am trying to derive an equation to compute the lat and lon variables given an x and y coordinates.
I already have the equations we are using in our game to derived the X and Y coordinates from lat and lon. 
Now we want to derive the formula in reverse. the code bellow shows the original formula to retrieve the X and Y given Lat and Lon that we are using. Well, computing for Lon is easy as it just involves transpose and division but cant seem to figure out how to do it for the latitude since it involves log and tangent functions.
Care to help math gurus?

bellow is our formula for getting x and y given Lat and Lon
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x &= 6371\frac{\text{lon}\pi}{180}\\
y &= 6371\log(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}4 + \left(\frac{\text{lat}\pi}{360}\right)\right))\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and for computing the Lon is fairly easy

$\text{lon} = \frac{x}{6371\frac{\pi}{180}}$;

I need help in the Lat..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read our guide to adding formatting [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by PI_4?

Comment: I assume with "PI" you mean $\pi$, but what is "PI_4" ? Perhaps $\pi/4$ ?

Comment: yes PI_4 is PI/4

Answer (score 2):

We do the following calculations
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{y}{6371} &=  \log \left[\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + (\text{lat} \frac{\pi}{360}\right)\right]  \\
\exp{\frac{y}{6371}} &= \exp\left\{ \log \left[\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + (\text{lat} \frac{\pi}{360}\right)\right] \right\} \\
\exp{\frac{y}{6371}} &= \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \text{lat} \frac{\pi}{360}\right) \\
\arctan\left[\exp{\frac{y}{6371}}\right] &= \arctan\left[ \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \text{lat} \frac{\pi}{360}\right) \right] \\
\arctan\left[\exp{\frac{y}{6371}}\right] &=  \frac{\pi}{4} + \text{lat}\frac{\pi}{360},
\end{align} 
$$
and derive that
$$
\text{lat} = \frac{360}{\pi}\left(\arctan\left[\exp{\frac{y}{6371}}\right] - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$